# What is causing inefficiency when parsing this QuerySet into tuples?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, performance, django-models

In a django app, I am attempting to parse a Queryset, representing individual time-series values *x* from *n* sensors, into tuples (t, x1, x2 ... x*n*), and thence into a json object in the format specified by google charts here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

*None* values are used as placeholders if no value was logged for a given timestamp from a particular sensor

The page load time is significant for a QuerySet with ~6500 rows (~3 seconds, run locally)

It's significantly longer on the server

http://54.162.202.222/pulogger/simpleview/?device=test

Profiling indicates that 99.9% of the time is spent on _winapi.WaitForSingleObject, (which I can't interpret) and manual profiling with a timer indicates that the server-side culprit is the while loop that iterates over the QuerySet and groups the values into tuples (line 23 in my code example)

Results are as-follows:

*basic gets (took 5ms)*

*queried data (took 0ms)*

*split data by sensor (took 981ms)*

*prepared column labels/types (took 0ms)*

*prepared json (took 27ms)*

*created context (took 0ms)*

For the sake of completeness, the timing function is as follows:

```
def print_elapsed_time(ref_datetime, description):
    print('{} (took {}ms)'.format(description, floor((datetime.now()-ref_datetime).microseconds/1000)))
    return datetime.now()
```

The code performing the processing and generating the view is as-follows:

```
def simpleview(request):
    time_marker = datetime.now()
    device_name = request.GET['device']
    device = Datalogger.objects.get(device_name=device_name)

    sensors = Sensor.objects.filter(datalogger=device).order_by('pk')
    sensor_count = len(sensors)  # should be no worse than count() since already-evaluated and cached.  todo: confirm

    #assign each sensor an index for the tuples (zero is used for time/x-axis)
    sensor_indices = {}
    for idx, sensor in enumerate(sensors, start=1):
        sensor_indices.update({sensor.sensor_name:idx})

    time_marker = print_elapsed_time(time_marker, 'basic gets')

    # process data into timestamp-grouped tuples accessible by sensor-index ([0] is timestamp)
    raw_data = SensorDatum.objects.filter(sensor__datalogger__device_name=device_name).order_by('timestamp', 'sensor')
    data = []
    data_idx = 0

    time_marker = print_elapsed_time(time_marker, 'queried data')

    while data_idx < len(raw_data):
        row_list = [raw_data[data_idx].timestamp]
        row_list.extend([None]*sensor_count)
        row_idx = 1

        while data_idx < len(raw_data) and raw_data[data_idx].timestamp == row_list[0]:
            row_idx = sensor_indices.get(raw_data[data_idx].sensor.sensor_name)
            row_list[row_idx] = raw_data[data_idx].value
            data_idx += 1
        data.append(tuple(row_list))

    time_marker = print_elapsed_time(time_marker, 'split data by sensor')

    column_labels = ['Time']
    column_types = ["datetime"]
    for sensor in sensors:
        column_labels.append(sensor.sensor_name)
        column_types.append("number")

    time_marker = print_elapsed_time(time_marker, 'prepared column labels/types')

    gchart_json = prepare_data_for_gchart(column_labels, column_types, data)


    time_marker = print_elapsed_time(time_marker, 'prepared json')


    context = {
        'device': device_name,
        'sensor_count': sensor_count,
        'sensor_indices': sensor_indices,
        'gchart_json': gchart_json,
    }

    time_marker = print_elapsed_time(time_marker, 'created context')

    return render(request, 'pulogger/simpleTimeSeriesView.html', context)
```

I'm new to python, so I expect that there's a poor choice of operation/collection I've used somewhere.  Unless I'm blind, it should run in O(n).

Obviously this isn't the *whole* problem since it only accounts for a part of the apparent load-time, but I figure this is a good place to start.

Comment: After trying a couple of further tests, the problem seems to be the evaluation of `raw_data[data_idx].sensor.sensor_name` in `row_idx = sensor_indices.get(raw_data[data_idx].sensor.sensor_name)`

So this is a problem with the way I'm handling django objects.

My understanding is that in each evaluation, it jumps to the relevant QuerySet element (SensorDatum) by index (fast), retrieves the associated Sensor object (possibly slow) and then gets its sensor_name (fast).

Would the best solution be to denormalise, copying sensor_name in SensorDatum's fields upon row insertion?

Comment: probably its best if you convert the querysets to list beforehand. Like `raw_data = list(SensorDatum.objects.filter(sensor__datalogger__device_name=device_name).order_by('timestamp', 'sensor'))`

Comment: @ruddra how does that interact with foreign-key fields?  Would the corresponding list element become some kind of object or just an int corresponding to its primary key?

Comment: Nope, you will be using it as it is. But instead of the queryset evaluating multiple times, it will be evaluated once. Hopefully it will increase performance, but I am not sure. More info can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Comment: @ruddra my understanding is that by instantiating/assigning the QuerySet to a variable (data) and accessing the nodes/members directly (without using all()/filter()/etc), the QS will not be evaluated multiple times.  Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: using `all()`, `filter()` does not evaluate queryset. Calling `len()`, `list`, `get()`, slicing queryset etc does.

Answer (score 0):

The "queried data" section is taking 0ms because that section is constructing the query, not executing your query against the database.

The query is being executed when it gets to this line: `while data_idx < len(raw_data):`, because to calculate the length of the `iterable` it must evaluate it.

So it may not be the loop that's taking most of the time, it's probably the query execution and evaluation.  You can evaluate the query before the main loop by wrapping the queryset in a `list()`, this will allow your `time_marker` to display how long the query is actually taking to execute.

Do you *need* the queryset evaluated to a model?  Alternatively you could use [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values) or [`.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to return an actual list of values, which skips serializing the query results into `Model` objects.  By doing this you also avoid having to return all the columns from the database, you only return the ones you need.

You could potential remove the table join in this query `SensorDatum.objects.filter(sensor__datalogger__device_name=device_name).order_by('timestamp', 'sensor')` by denormalizing your schema (if possible) to have the device_name field on the sensor.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise calling length caused re-evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You have queries running under a loop. You can use `select_related` to cache related objects beforehand.

**Example**:

```
raw_data = SensorDatum.objects.filter(
    sensor__datalogger__device_name=device_name
).order_by(
    'timestamp',
    'sensor'
).select_related('sensor') # this will fetch and cache sensor objects and will prevent further db queries in the loop
```

Ref: [select_related Django 2.1 Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Comment: Thank-you.  I've denormalised the model already, but will attempt to use this method instead.